# Configure NLog in ASP.NET Core 2.0 without nlog.config file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nlog

I want to create a NuGet for common things used at any ASP.NET Core application, and I want to add a Log manager inside taking advantage of NLog. Regarding this, following the tutorial on NLog it seems like I am forced to add a nlog.config at any application that is using my own NuGet.

Is there any option to avoid this config file, maybe creating a configuration in code, or at least to embed it on my own NuGet?

Thanks a lot in advance

NOTE: [followed NLog getting started tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2)

Comment: making configuratuon in code makes you dependent to code. why would you do that?

Comment: Because I want to create a common configuration, without depending of nlog.config file. In addition, I want to allow making some configurations from the target project, but again from code (for example when you are registering services on Startup)

Comment: See this: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following the tutorial then you can replace this call:

```
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

With your own custom NLog LoggingConfiguration:

```
var nlogConfig = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
var nlogFileTarget = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") { FileName = "file.txt" };
nlogConfig.AddRuleForAllLevels(nlogFileTarget);
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(nlogConfig).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is just what I wanted to do, thank you :)